# UILocalNotification with fireDate in the past, but with repeatInterval

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

If I create a `UILocalNotification` & set its fireDate in the past & with a repeatInterval, will it fire once repeatInterval is due next time in future? Or will an `UILocalNotification` only fire with a future fireDate ?

Answer (score 1):

It will.
If you set in the application a `-fireDate` in the past, it will be fired immediately and should be handled inside the UIApplicationDelegate `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method.

If you set also a repeat interval your notification will continue to be fired at the exact time multiplied per the `-repeatInterval`

Comment: Are you sure? this here http://tiku.io/questions/2708479/objective-c-ios-repeating-uilocalnotification-set-to-date-in-past states otherwise...

Comment: mumble... I was since your comment. Anyway you can do an easy test on device. Set your notification and change the date.

Comment: I check on an app of mine that creates an amount of notification I was pretty sure that it was going to set a notification  even if in the past, but I've seen that if the date is in the past I create a notification just by adding a day.